# How to toggle elements with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, toggle

I am building a website page that has like 16 items of apparel.

I want a simple text navigation that has the option to show and hide products that are either for Men, Women, and All.

Navigation

```
<ul class="sortNav">
<li class="first">View:</li>
<li class="men button">Men</li>
<li class="women button">Women</li>
<li class="all button active">All</li>
</ul>
```

Products Code

```
<span class="prod men">Guys shirt</span>
<span class="prod men">Guys Pant </span>
<span class="prod women">Girls Pant</span>
<span class="prod women">Girls Pant</span>
```

Tricky part 
Only one button can be "active". And only that class will be visible (one or two) will be triggered.

Thanks in advance.

Thanks! Kinda combined the two responses. Check this out...

```
$('.products li.prod').toggle(true);

$('.sortNav li.button').click(function () {
    $('.sortNav li.button').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active'); });

$('.sortNav li.men').click(function () {
    $('.products li.prod').toggle(false);
    $('.products li.men').toggle(true); });

$('.sortNav li.women').click(function () {
    $('.products li.prod').toggle(false);
    $('.products li.women').toggle(true); });

$('.sortNav li.all').click(function () {
    $('.products li.prod').toggle(true);
```

Comment: So you want to remove `active` class from each one right?

Comment: I thought he just wanted to toggle the products he is showing based on the ul they clicked

Comment: So, not any single answer accepted? For none of your questions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I Compacted a little bit the code, but you should also change the li items

HTML:

```
<ul class="sortNav">
<li class="first">View:</li>
<li section="mens" class="men button">Men</li>
<li section="womens" class="women button">Women</li>
<li section="all" class="all button active">All</li>
</ul>

<div id="all" class="section">All Clothing</div>
<div id="mens" class="section">Mens Clothing</div>
<div id="womens" class="section">Womens Clothing</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('li.button').click(function(){ //listens to each element li with class button
        $('li.button').removeClass('active'); //removes 'active' class from all of them
        $(this).addClass('active'); //adds the class to this one

        $('.section').toggle(false);
        $('#'+$(this).attr('section')).toggle(true);
    });

    $(".section").toggle(false);
});
```

As you see I added a section attribute, which you can assign to toggle(true) as an id. It's a bit risky, but it works.

Comment: yea this sounds right...what about adding the showing/hiding the products as well?

Comment: @Buildingbrick checkout my example it details how to show and hide

Comment: very nice!! Thanks. You are pro!

Comment: @Kor haha you hijacked my fiddle

Comment: @kmb385 oh lol I didn't even see your answer xD, I thought of doing that way, the problem is that each DOM element needs a different id, so you would have problems for showing/hiding them in some places

Comment: I'm talking about using the same id in more than one dom element. For example, by using classes jquery returns an array of items (say $('.button') would return 3 elements), but $('#mens') would only return the first instance of any object with id mens. Or at least that's what I've always seen in my projects

Answer (score 1):

Check out this js fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9kL7q/3/ ***NEW Fiddle**

Html:

```
<ul class="sortNav">
<li class="first">View:</li>
<li id="men" class="men button">Men</li>
<li id="women" class="women button">Women</li>
<li id="all" class="all button active">All</li>
</ul>

<div id="all" class="section">All Clothing</div>
<div id="men" class="section">Mens Clothing</div>
<div id="women" class="section">Womens Clothing</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(".section").not("#all").toggle(false);

$(".section").click(function(){
    $(".section").toggle(false);
    $("#" + $(this).attr("id")).toggle(true);
});
```

Comment: is there a way to normalize this anyway? Or bring the code down to a single function that will work for all three buttons?

Comment: @Buildingbrick i updated the fiddle and this code give it a look

Comment: Looks good! But "All" is actually just "Men" and "Women" so having an all "section" would be redundant...right?

Comment: @Buildingbrick yes it could be, could you give me credit for the work I did?

Comment: @Buildingbrick In my earlier post i was wondering if you could accept my answer or at least one up my post since it made its way into your question you must be using the new code.

Comment: Don't have enough reputation points. Will do once I get some more.

Answer (score 0):

@kmb385: I fixed the jquery selectors for you to make "mens" and "womens" work on click http://jsfiddle.net/9kL7q/2/

Comment: This will work as well. Never used the "toggle(false)" before, usually use "hide()". I guess toggle works better since we are using toggle as the event.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.sortNav li.button').click(function() {
        // Set this button as active
        $('.sortNav li.button').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');

        // Show and hide items that do or don't match this button's classes
        // (.prod.all won't get messed with, but you could make the HTML say
        // 'class="prod men women"' instead and it should work)
        $('.prod.women').toggle($(this).hasClass('womens'));
        $('.prod.men').toggle($(this).hasClass('mens'));
    });
});
```

Use with HTML that looks like this:

```
<ul class="sortNav">
    <li class="first">View:</li>
    <li class="mens button">Men</li>
    <li class="womens button">Women</li>
    <li class="mens womens button active">All</li>
</ul>

<div class="prod all">an item for everyone</div>
<div class="prod women">Womens item</div>
<div class="prod men">Mens item</div>
<div class="prod men">More Mens stuff</div>
<div class="prod women">More Womens stuff</div>
```

Comment: what is the .hasClass() event for?

Comment: It tests whether the element (the button in this case) has "mens" or "womens" among its CSS classes.  The code will take any element that has both the "prod" and "men" classes, and (because of how `toggle` works) show it if the *button* has the "mens" class, and hide it otherwise.  Similar story with the women's stuff.  The key to making this work is to give the "all" button both "mens" and "womens" classes -- that makes both of the `hasClass` calls return `true`, and thus makes everything show.

Comment: BTW, for reference, `.hasClass` isn't an event.  It's a method (basically, a function on an object)...in this case on the object that jQuery objects (the things you get from `$('whatever')`) inherit from.  Things like `.click` are methods too.   jQuery just happens to use them to wire up event handlers and trigger events.